# pgfplots: `nan` in `meta expr` causes "Missing number" error

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I want to draw a table/matrix of color-values, where some of the values are missing.
Despite having tried using `unbounded coords=jump` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28792/pgfplot-missing-values-in-table-data)), I get the following error:

> ```
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
> <to be read again>
>                   n
> l.59 \end{axis}
> ```

How do I tell pgfplots to include the rows and columns for the missing value, and simply skip those missing value?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
yitem,xitem,val
a,R,0.1
b,S,nan
c,T,0.3
d,U,nan
e,V,0.5
f,W,0.6
g,X,nan
h,Y,0.8
i,Z,nan
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z},
    xtick=data,
    symbolic y coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i},
    ytick=data,
    unbounded coords=jump,
]
\addplot[
    mark=square*,
    only marks,
    scatter,
    point meta=explicit,
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    x expr=\coordindex,
    y expr=\coordindex,
    meta expr=\thisrow{val},
] {\datatable};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got the basic idea for the matrix/table from [this page](http://www.dgsiegel.net/news/2011_12_05-creating_beautiful_graphics_with_pgfplots).

I have added `\listfiles` to my preamble and received the following pgf-looking output:

> ```
> pgfplots.sty    2011/12/29 v1.5.1 (git show 1.5.1-4-g53e640f )
>      pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
>   pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
>   pgfrcs.code.tex
>  pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
>   pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
>   pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
>   pgfsys.code.tex
> pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
> pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
>  pgfcore.code.tex
> pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
> pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
>   pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
>  pgfkeys.sty
>  pgfkeys.code.tex
>   pgffor.code.tex
> pgfplotstable.sty    2011/12/19 Part of pgfplots
> ```

Comment: I don't get an error when running this code. What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: I added some output. It looks like its version 1.5.1

Comment: The current version is 1.9. Could you update the package and check whether the error persists?

Comment: I updated to 1.9 as you suggested, and now it works. If you want to type that up as an answer, I'll make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a more recent version of PGFPlots (the current one is 1.9).