# PGFPlot - Leading missing values in table data ignored, but other missing values interpolated

Tags: pgfplots

I know that leading missing values are ignored from [PGFPlot - Missing values in table data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28792/pgfplot-missing-values-in-table-data). However, I found that when missing values pop up again later in a table, there is interpolation between the two closest observations.

Is it possible for pgfplot to also ignore these missing values, that is, to interrupt the line when missing values reappear?

Hope the example helps.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{performance.data}
x   Italy Ireland
1   NaN 63.99
2   NaN 62.005
3   NaN 62.28
4   NaN 62.19
5   NaN 62.05
6   NaN 61.805
7   NaN 61.25
8   NaN 61.875
9   NaN 62.3
10  NaN 62.625
11  NaN 62.28
12  NaN 62.685
13  NaN 62.51
14  NaN 62.445
15  NaN 62.73
16  NaN 62.79
17  NaN 62.78
18  NaN 63.3
19  NaN 63.51
20  NaN 62.73
21  NaN 62.255
22  NaN 62.11
23  NaN 63.39
24  NaN 65.69
25  NaN 66.32
26  NaN 66.76
27  245.139 67.175
28  241.899 65.565
29  238.761 64.735
30  232.078 64.905
31  231.107 62.095
32  236.187 60.015
33  232.242 63.68
34  230.068 63.12
35  221.385 62.9
36  213.458 64.79
37  213.255 64.795
38  221.349 65.325
39  221.219 65.245
40  NaN 69.275
41  NaN 69.275
42  NaN 68.27
43  NaN 68.265
44  NaN 67.765
45  NaN 67.765
46  NaN 67.26
47  NaN 67.265
48  NaN 66.76
49  NaN 66.76
50  NaN 66.76
51  NaN 66.755
52  NaN 67.26
53  NaN 67.255
54  NaN 67.76
55  NaN 64.75
56  NaN 66.75
57  NaN 66.265
58  NaN 66.255
59  NaN 66.26
60  NaN 66.26
61  NaN 66.26
62  NaN 66.26
63  NaN 66.26
64  NaN 66.26
65  NaN 66.765
66  NaN 66.765
67  NaN 67.27
68  NaN 67.265
69  NaN 67.765
70  NaN 67.265
71  NaN 67.265
72  NaN 67.27
73  NaN 67.265
74  NaN 67.265
75  NaN 67.27
76  NaN 67.27
77  NaN 67.275
78  NaN 67.27
79  NaN 67.775
80  NaN 68.78
81  NaN 68.785
82  NaN 68.785
83  NaN 68.78
84  NaN 67.775
85  NaN 67.78
86  NaN 67.78
87  NaN 68.29
88  NaN 68.29
89  NaN 68.79
90  NaN 68.795
91  NaN 68.8
92  NaN 68.805
93  NaN 68.8
94  NaN 68.795
95  NaN 68.8
96  NaN 68.805
97  NaN 68.81
98  NaN 68.805
99  NaN 68.8
100 NaN 68.805
101 NaN 68.81
102 NaN 68.815
103 NaN 69.31
104 NaN 69.305
105 NaN 69.31
106 NaN 69.315
107 NaN 69.82
108 NaN 69.305
109 NaN 69.31
110 NaN 69.315
111 NaN 69.82
112 NaN 69
113 NaN 69.825
114 NaN 70.32
115 NaN 68.31
116 NaN 64.79
117 NaN 64.8
118 NaN 63.78
119 NaN 63.78
120 NaN 63.79
121 NaN 63.785
122 NaN 67.31
123 NaN 66.3
124 NaN 65.79
125 NaN 64.79
126 NaN 64.79
127 NaN 64.795
128 NaN 64.29
129 NaN 64.29
130 NaN 63.29
131 NaN 63.785
132 NaN 63.79
133 NaN 63.285
134 NaN 63.79
135 NaN 63.29
136 NaN 63.29
137 NaN 63.795
138 NaN 63.79
139 NaN 64.29
140 NaN 64.29
141 NaN 63.79
142 NaN 63.795
143 NaN 63.79
144 NaN 64.29
145 NaN 63.79
146 NaN 63.8
147 NaN 64.3
148 NaN 63.79
149 NaN 63.79
150 NaN 63.795
151 NaN 63.795
152 NaN 63.8
153 NaN 63.29
154 NaN 63.28
155 NaN 63.785
156 NaN 63.29
157 NaN 63.29
158 NaN 62.785
159 NaN 62.79
160 NaN 62.79
161 NaN 62.79
162 NaN 62.295
163 NaN 62.29
164 NaN 62.29
165 NaN 62.365
166 NaN 62.15
167 NaN 69.02
168 NaN 65.885
169 NaN 64.89
170 NaN 65.395
171 NaN 65.395
172 NaN 64.9
173 NaN 64.575
174 NaN 65.185
175 NaN 65.19
176 NaN 65.19
177 NaN 65.53
178 NaN 65.355
179 NaN 65.355
180 NaN 66.03
181 NaN 65.15
182 NaN 66.03
183 NaN 66.03
184 NaN 66.03
185 NaN 66.03
186 NaN 66.36
187 NaN 66.37
188 NaN 66.36
189 NaN 66.36
190 NaN 66.36
191 NaN 66.36
192 NaN 65.7
193 NaN 65.355
194 NaN 65.69
195 NaN 65.69
196 NaN 65.69
197 NaN 65.7
198 NaN 65.69
199 NaN 65.69
200 NaN 65.69
201 NaN 65.69
202 NaN 65.7
203 NaN 65.69
204 NaN 65.69
205 NaN 65.69
206 NaN 65.695
207 NaN 65.7
208 NaN 65.695
209 NaN 65.36
210 NaN 65.36
211 NaN 65.36
212 NaN 65.36
213 NaN 65.36
214 NaN 65.15
215 NaN 65.365
216 NaN 65.365
217 NaN 65.205
218 NaN 65.2
219 NaN 64.865
220 NaN 64.87
221 NaN 65.54
222 NaN 65.54
223 NaN 65.2
224 NaN 65.2
225 NaN 64.87
226 NaN 64.865
227 NaN 64.87
228 NaN 64.865
229 NaN 64.53
230 NaN 64.53
231 NaN 64.53
232 NaN 64.2
233 NaN 64.2
234 NaN 64.195
235 NaN 63.86
236 NaN 63.86
237 NaN 63.87
238 NaN 63.86
239 NaN 63.87
240 NaN 63.87
241 NaN 63.87
242 165.268 63.88
243 168.008 63.87
244 172.744 63.87
245 172.773 63.87
246 172.258 63.54
247 167.017 63.54
248 160.834 63.54
249 163.177 63.53
250 158.097 63.53
251 153.947 63.535
252 155.623 63.54
253 155.832 64.2
254 160.137 64.21
255 163.648 63.87
256 160.586 63.87
257 154.958 63.545
258 154.942 63.54
259 159.679 63.3
260 161.574 63.3
261 166.478 63.3
262 164.588 65.825
263 168.554 66
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
    \addplot table {performance.data};
    \addplot table [y=Italy] {performance.data};
    \addplot table [y=Ireland] {performance.data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Red line (Italy) contains NaNs. Brown line has no NaNs]

Comment: Add option `unbounded coords=jump` to `\addplot`, eg. `\addplot+[unbounded coords=jump] table [y=Italy] {performance.data};` See the accepted answer to the question which you have linked. Note that in your example the values for Italy are plotted twice. You have to add the option to both plots or better remove the first or the second plot.

Comment: But then there's still the line connecting the marks, which I would like to be interrupted.

Comment: No. `\addplot table {performance.data};` and `\addplot table [y=Italy] {performance.data};` plots the same data (Italy). You can remove one of these plots or you have to add the option to both plots. Or better remove one of this.

Comment: Of course, I looked over it. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: You can also add the option to the `axis` environment: `\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add option `unbounded coords=jump` for the plots.

Short example:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}% <- added!
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{performance.data}
x   Italy Ireland
1   NaN 63.99
27  245.139 67.175
39  221.219 65.245
214 NaN 65.15
242 165.268 63.88
263 168.554 66
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
    %\addplot+[unbounded coords=jump] table {performance.data};
    \addplot+[unbounded coords=jump] table [y=Italy] {performance.data};
    \addplot table [y=Ireland] {performance.data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}% <- added!
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{performance.data}
x   Italy Ireland
1   NaN 63.99
27  245.139 67.175
39  221.219 65.245
214 NaN 65.15
242 165.268 63.88
263 168.554 66
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]% <- changed
    %\addplot table {performance.data};
    \addplot table [y=Italy] {performance.data};
    \addplot table [y=Ireland] {performance.data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]